# What is the problem about "fixed" position in Firefox mobile?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In the following path, when you play a music in the Firefox browser on mobile, a player will be displayed in the bottom of view-port, when you work with player some elements will be hided!

I have a such problem with a fixed element which has zero bottom! How do I can fix it?

https://www.qwant.com/music/album/lonny-montem-what-kind-of-music-do-you-play-ep/overview

Comment: I founded it happened when body has scroll and I scroll to the end of the page!

Comment: A possible way to solve this problem is perhaps not to use `{ bottom: 0; }` and instead position the element from the top, if its height is set. For example: `{ height: 80px; top: calc(100vh - 80px; }`. (Your solution below is a possibility, but as it prevents the address bar from collapsing can be a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!

It caused by hiding address bar when you scrolling in the Firefox mobile app.

I resolve it by preventing hiding address bar with adding some styles to the parent element or a wrapper in the body (You can disable this option in the customize section of Firefox browser to test).

```
 .wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
```